# Passing dynamic method name to another method as parameter in java

Tags: java, java-8

I have a calling method as genJsonPayload(). Inside this method I am calling a replace() method to replace some string with randomly generated values. I want to call the replace() by passing another method as parameter. My sample code below.

```java
public static StringBuffer replace(String jsonparam, StringBuffer jsondata, String replacedWith) { 
    int start = 0;
    int last = 0;
    while (jsondata.indexOf(jsonparam)!= jsondata.lastIndexOf(jsonparam)) {
        start = jsondata.indexOf(jsonparam);
        last = start + jsonparam.length();
        jsondata = jsondata.replace(start,last,replacedwith); 
    }
    start = jsondata.indexOf(jsonparam);
    last = start + jsonparam.length();
    jsondata = jsondata.replace(start,last,replacedwith); 
    
    return jsondata;
}
    
public String genJSONPayload(String jsonpayload) {
    StringBuffer sbuffer = new StringBuffer(jsonpayload);
    
    try {
        jsondata = replace("expectedAreaCode",jsondata, CreateRandom.createAreaCDRandom());
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        ....
    }
    try {
        jsondata = replace("expectedextensionNo",jsondata, CreateRandom.createExtensionNumberRandom());
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        ....
    }
}
```

**Json payload as below :**

```json
{
    ...
    ...
    "phonenumber": [
    {
     "areaCode": "expectedAreaCode",
     "extensionNo": "expectedextensionNo",
      ...
    }
    {
     "areaCode": "expectedAreaCode",
     "extensionNo": "expectedextensionNo",
      ...
    }
    {
     "areaCode": "expectedAreaCode",
     "extensionNo": "expectedextensionNo",
      ...
    }],
    ...
    ...
    
}
```

**Note :**
CreateRandom.createAreaCDRandom() return a random String.

**Problem statement :**
My requirement is to replace "expectedAreaCode" of json file with randomly generated area code using the replace() method. But as I am executing the CreateRandom.createAreaCDRandom() from genJSONPayload() only once so replacedWith in replace() method is getting store with fixed area code and for all the area code in the json array phonenumber, I am getting the same areacode.

**Question :**

Instead of passing the replacedWith String to the replace() method, can I pass the createAreaCDRandom() static method as parameter and instead of executing createAreaCDRandom() method from genJSONPayload, then I will execute it inside replace method multiple times inside the while loop. I have more than 5 such random mentods, basically for different json parameters.
How can I pass the createAreaCDRandom(), createExtensionNumberRandom(), etc methods as the parameter in the repace() method?

Comment: Can you indent your code so that it's readable? Stack Overflow shows a preview of your post before you submit. Please pay attention to it and fix any formatting issues.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. @Michael is right. When you are not doing the minimal effort of having you IDE indent your code, you are also leaving us with the impression that your question is not worth doing a minimal effort for, thus reducing your chance of a qualified answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Supplier class as a method parameter (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Supplier.html).

Then You can pass lambda or method reference to provide value generating logic.

```
public static StringBuffer replace(String jsonparam, StringBuffer jsondata, Supplier<String> supplier) {
    int start = 0;
    int last = 0;
    while (jsondata.indexOf(jsonparam) != jsondata.lastIndexOf(jsonparam)) {
        start = jsondata.indexOf(jsonparam);
        last = start + jsonparam.length();
        jsondata = jsondata.replace(start, last, supplier.get());
    }
    start = jsondata.indexOf(jsonparam);
    last = start + jsonparam.length();
    jsondata = jsondata.replace(start, last, supplier.get());

    return jsondata;
}


public String genJSONPayload(String jsonpayload) {
    StrignBuffer sbuffer = new StrignBuffer(jsonpayload);

    try{
        jsondata = replace("expectedAreaCode",jsondata, CreateRandom::createAreaCDRandom);
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        ....
    }
    try{
        jsondata = replace("expectedextensionNo",jsondata, CreateRandom::createExtensionNumberRandom);
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        ....
    }
}
```